# Payload in Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Can someone explain to me what is payload in redux-toolkit?

Where does this value come from?

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export interface CounterState {
  value: number
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0,
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    },
  },
})


export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions


export default counterSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action.payload` created by [createAction](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction) function. These three fields (`payload`, `meta` and `error`) adhere to the specification of [Flux Standard Actions](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action#actions).

[Payload](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action#payload):

> The optional `payload` property MAY be any type of value. It represents the payload of the action. Any information about the action that is not the type or status of the action should be part of the `payload` field. By convention, if `error` is `true`, the `payload` SHOULD be an error object. This is akin to rejecting a promise with an error object.

Answer (score 0):

`payload` is the name of data that you are sending to your store to update the corresponding reducer.

```
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions
```

`increment`,`decrement` and `incrementByAmount` those all are action creator functions. the name `counterSlice.actions` is misleading, I think it should be `counterSlice.actionCreators`. When you call any of those `action creator` functions it returns an `action` object.

`action objects` are plain javascript objects that have two properties:

```
{ type:"spcialTypeName",payload:"data that you are sending" }
```

If you call `increment()` it will return this:

```
 // type name is created by this pattern: "slicerName/reducerName"
 {type: "counter/increment", payload:undefined}
```

`payload` is `undefined` because you did not pass anything to the action creator function. But if you called `increment("my first task")`, this will return

```
 {type:"counter/increment", payload:"my first task"}
```

Note that you cannot pass multipe arguments to `action creators` in redux-toolkit. for example

```
 increment("my first task","my second task")
```

this will not cause an error but your slicer will accept the first argument as payload. If you need to pass multiple arguments,you need to pass an object. For example:

```
 increment({firstTask:"my first task",secondTask:"my second task"})`
```

this action creator will return this

```
 {type:"counter/increment", payload:{firstTask:"my first task",secondTask:"my second task"}}
```

notice that this time payload is an object.